# Find a website at some geographical location

Tags: internet, diagnostic

The http responses returned from my server are very slow. After testing a number of things out, I suspect some router along the way has implemented a firewall to inspect higher level protocol data, possibly http protocol data. In order to determine whether that is true, I would like to access a website that is hosted by my server provider that is located at the same location. Is there a way to figure out the domain name of some server located at the same location? All I have to go on is the IP address of my own server, so I assume that that some website should exist that uses an address within a range of the one mine is using.

Answer (score -1):

Found this cool tool: http://reverseip.domaintools.com/

Unlike most other reverse IP address tools, this lists the actual domain of site and not the service provider's domain.